# Jquery: replace content only if the new content is different

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a php file which is called every X second in ajax to refresh a content. This php file return a js file wich must change the html content of a div with a effect.

But I would want to change this content only if the new is different! Else, I have a div which refresh itself with the effect even if it's the sames contents!

I tested with this code:

```
if ($('#mydiv').html()!=data_insertion) $('#mydiv').fadeTo("fast", 0, function () {$(this).html(data_insertion).fadeTo("fast", 1)});
```

But this code isn't cross browser... Indeed, my data_insertion variable contains some html content. And each browser insert it changing the attribut order etc. That's why, $('#mydiv').html() is never equal to data_insertion.

Comment: Can you just use the .text(), or is that not sufficient?

Comment: Hum in fact, for exemple, I have data_insertion="<div class="x" name="x" id="x"></div>"; Chrome will insert "<div  name="x" id="x" class="x"></div>" and IE "<div name="x" class="x" id="x"></div>" for exemple. So the contents will allways be differents even if they arre the same in fact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a local cache of the result, attached to the element.
In your ajax callback do something like:

```
if (jQuery.data($('#mydiv')[0], 'last_data_insertion') != data_insertion) {
    // Update DOM content
    $('#mydiv').fadeTo("fast", 0, function () {$(this).html(data_insertion).fadeTo("fast", 1)});

    // Reset the local cache
    jQuery.data($('#mydiv')[0], 'last_data_insertion', data_insertion);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's what i would want to do... Compare data_insertion directly to the last data_insertion (and not use $('#mydiv') to get the last content inserted by the browser to evict errors of different parsing etc)...

Comment: Where i put var last_data_insertion = ''; ? Because as i said, it's a php file get by ajax every X seconds...

Comment: By the way in fact, in the php file returned, it's 20 lines like i show you. And i must do the check for each one before insert. So the ajax callback is hard no?

Comment: If it's the same call returning 20 lines, there is no problem, the above solution is OK. To avoid the initialization of last_data_insertion in global scope you can attach it to the element data store (changed my answer to use element store)

Comment: Excellent solution with the data! I started with your former solution (the vars), it worked! But the data method is the best I think!