# Replace data only if new content is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I started out with a problem extremely similar to this one: [Jquery : remplace content only if the new content is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087418/jquery-remplace-content-only-if-the-new-content-is-different)

I've tried the accepted solution, and it doesn't seem to work the way it is supposed to. I tried first the native solution, just putting in my div stuff. Then I tried looking up the function on jQuery's site here: http://api.jquery.com/data/ and fixed my code accordingly to the last example. I tried alerting the data to see what exactly was going on, but it's fair amount of data, which is why I have everything MD5 hashed.

My problem is that the first alert is coming back undefined, and the second one is, in fact, defined going out. Am I doing something wrong? What would cause this stored data to disappear?

My current code:

```
function setDiv(data) {
    newData = md5(data);
    if ($('#myDiv1').data('oldData') != newData) {
        $('#myDiv1').fadeTo("fast", 0, function () {$(this).html(data).fadeTo("fast", 1)});

        alert($('#myDiv1').data('oldData'))

        $('#myDiv1').data('oldData',md5(data));
        alert($('#myDiv1').data('oldData'))
    }
}
```

And my script headers (the second one is for the md5 function):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5.js"></script>
```

For all intents and purposes, the data being fed to the function is correct... what I could see of it, anyways. It still functions after being set. But I just don't want it to refresh every time setTimeout does it's thing, plus I rather like things fading out and in, rather than just BAM.

Right now, with that current code, it just fades in and out, even though the data is the same. And obviously alerts me undefined on start, and a md5 on finish. Same md5 on finish every time, so it's definitely the same data. But the first alert is just undefined is being the problem.

Function that submits the data to the function above:

```
function loadDivContent(arg1,arg2) {
    $.post('divContent.php',{arg1:arg1,arg2:arg2})
    .done(function(data) {
        setDiv(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: where does .data for the element initially get set?

Comment: from a $post function.

function loadDivContent(var1,var2) {
 $.post('divContent.php',{var1:var1,var2:var2})
 .done(function(data) {
  setDiv(data)
 });
}

The data is received just fine. It sets just fine with the function in my OP. Just it won't "save" to .data like it should.

Comment: if the post is sync and you check it on the very next line or if it is async and you check it in the the callback (right after it is set) is it there?

Comment: The first alert should show "undefined" the first time the function is called, because at that point you've not set the `oldData` value yet. Where's the `setTimeout` that you mentioned?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I edited in the function that sends the data to the function in question, since comments don't seem to have proper formatting.

Comment: Save data in a variable and check if is different

Comment: Yes the first time, it should. The second and the third and the fourth and the fifth and the sixth and the seventh time, etc, that this function is called, though? It's always undefined at that point. Always.

Comment: The setTimeout is in yet another function. The one that loads every div that I want reloaded. All that function is are a bunch of calls to other functions. Easier for management than having a whole bunch of setTimeouts for multiple items, when I want them all refreshed at the same time.

Comment: I'd suggest a different approach. Send an MD5 hash of the current data to `divContent.php` (as an argument) and let it check if the current data matches the new one (the data it would send). If it does match, respond only with the [HTTP response code 304](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5); otherwise, send a normal response. Then your JavaScript only needs to check the response code and you also save on your bandwidth.

Comment: _"The one that loads every div that I want reloaded."_ Does it recreate the whole `'#meDiv1'` element? That would wipe out previous data values.

Comment: Vedran: Sounds good, I'll try that. nnnnnn: no, it creates all the content between the div tags, and then sets the div with that content. The .data command is after the set, though, and the first call to the .data (the if statement, and I've done an alert before the if statement, too; same result: undefined) is before it is set. Don't think that's the problem, but I'll try a few things.

Comment: I found the problem. There was a <script src> tag in my divContent.php for some reason. I guess that was affecting it. Seeing as how it wasn't needed, since I'm loading it into the main page anyways, which already has the src... I removed it and everything works fine.

Thanks for all the responses.